# Common color bar for image plots

Tags: r, image, matrix, plot

I have to plot a figure (image plot; z ~ x+y) with four subplots and common color bar in the bottom. The plots should be arranged with 2 rows and 2 columns. I tried the code below. What changes do I need to make to save these plots into single figure having common color bar for all the subplots?

```
library(akima)
library(sinkr)
#----Generate random xyz data----
x = seq(0.1,0.8,0.02)
y = seq(0.1,5,0.1)
z1 <- runif(length(x)*length(y),0,600)  # Sample 1
z1 <- matrix(unlist(z1), nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
z2 <- runif(length(x)*length(y),0,600)  # Sample 2
z2 <- matrix(unlist(z2), nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
z3 <- runif(length(x)*length(y),0,600)  # Sample 3
z3 <- matrix(unlist(z3), nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
z4 <- runif(length(x)*length(y),0,600)  # Sample 4
z4 <- matrix(unlist(z4), nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
#----Image Plot----
png(
  filename="~/plot.PNG",
  width=12,
  height=8,
  units="in",
  res=600)
par(family = "serif")
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) # Arrange plots in 2 rows and 2 columns

# Basic settings
ncolors <- 64
colors <- jetPal(ncolors)
zlim <- c(0,600)
breaks <- c(seq(zlim[1], zlim[2], length.out = ncolors), 1e6)
layout(matrix(1:2,1,2), widths = c(4,1), heights = 4) # To plot colorbar besides the main plot 
#---Subplot 1----
image(x, y, z1, col = colors, breaks = breaks, zlim = zlim,cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.5,xlab="",ylab="",ylim=c(0.1,5.0),xlim=c(0.1,0.8))
title(ylab=expression(y),line=2.0,cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(xlab=expression(x),line=2.5,cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(main="(a)",adj=0, cex.main=1.5)
imageScale(z = z1, ylim = zlim, zlim = zlim, col = colors, breaks = breaks, axis.pos = 2)
text(x=-1.8,y=500,labels = expression(g[sc]~(mmol~m^-2~s^-1)),xpd=NA,srt=90,cex=1.5,family='serif') 

#---Subplot 2----
image(x, y, z2, col = colors, breaks = breaks, zlim =zlim,cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.5,xlab="",ylab="",ylim=c(0.1,5.0),xlim=c(0.1,0.8))
title(ylab=expression(y),line=2.0,cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(xlab=expression(x),line=2.5,cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(main="(b)",adj=0, cex.main=1.5)
imageScale(z = z2, ylim = zlim, zlim = zlim, col = colors, breaks = breaks, 
       axis.pos = 2)
text(x=-1.8,y=500,labels = expression(g[sc]~(mmol~m^-2~s^-1)),xpd=NA,srt=90,cex=1.5,family='serif') 
#---Subplot 3----
image(x, y, z3, col = colors, breaks = breaks, zlim =zlim,cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.5,xlab="",ylab="",ylim=c(0.1,5.0),xlim=c(0.1,0.8))
title(ylab=expression(y),line=2.0,cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(xlab=expression(x),line=2.5,cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(main="(c)",adj=0, cex.main=1.5)
imageScale(z = z3, ylim = zlim, zlim = zlim, col = colors, breaks = breaks, 
       axis.pos = 2)
text(x=-1.8,y=500,labels = expression(g[sc]~(mmol~m^-2~s^-1)),xpd=NA,srt=90,cex=1.5,family='serif')
#---Subplot 4----
image(x, y, z4, col = colors, breaks = breaks, zlim = zlim,cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.5,xlab="",ylab="",ylim=c(0.1,5.0),xlim=c(0.1,0.8))
title(ylab=expression(y),line=2.0,cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(xlab=expression(x),line=2.5,cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(main="(d)",adj=0, cex.main=1.5)
imageScale(z = z4, ylim = zlim, zlim = zlim, col = colors, breaks = breaks, 
       axis.pos = 2)
text(x=-1.8,y=500,labels = expression(g[sc]~(mmol~m^-2~s^-1)),xpd=NA,srt=90,cex=1.5,family='serif') 

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually just slightly modify the `layout` matrix and the `height` and `width`. The numbers correspond to the plots, the `imageScale` is also a new plot. If you want one plot to spread across multiple cells, just repeat the number. There's a `layout.show()` function that helps you, use `layout.show(5)` to check how you layout will look like with your 5 plots. Setting `mfrow=` in `par` is redundant and only disturbs the `layout`.

```
library('akima')
library('sinkr')

#----Generate random xyz data----
x <- seq(0.1, 0.8, 0.02)
y <- seq(0.1, 5, 0.1)
z1 <- runif(length(x)*length(y), 0, 600) # Sample 1
z1 <- matrix(unlist(z1), nrow=length(x), ncol=length(y))
z2 <- runif(length(x)*length(y), 0, 600) # Sample 2
z2 <- matrix(unlist(z2), nrow=length(x), ncol=length(y))
z3 <- runif(length(x)*length(y), 0, 600) # Sample 3
z3 <- matrix(unlist(z3), nrow=length(x), ncol=length(y))
z4 <- runif(length(x)*length(y), 0, 600) # Sample 4
z4 <- matrix(unlist(z4), nrow=length(x), ncol=length(y))

#----Image Plot----
png(
 filename="~/plot.PNG",
 width=8,
 height=12,
 units="in",
 res=600)
par(family="serif")
# par(mfrow=c(2, 2)) # Arrange plots in 2 rows and 2 columns

# Basic settings
ncolors <- 64
colors <- jetPal(ncolors)
zlim <- c(0, 600)
breaks <- c(seq(zlim[1], zlim[2], length.out=ncolors), 1e6)
layout(matrix(c(1:4, rep(5, 4)), 4, 2)
    , widths=c(4.25, .75), heights=rep(4, 4)
    ) # To plot colorbar besides the main plot
# layout.show(5)

#---Subplot 1-------------------------------------------------------------------
image(x, y, z1, col=colors, breaks=breaks, zlim=zlim, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5,
      xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(0.1, 5.0), xlim=c(0.1, 0.8))
title(ylab=expression(y), line=2.0, cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(xlab=expression(x), line=2.5, cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(main="(a)", adj=0, cex.main=1.5)

#---Subplot 2-------------------------------------------------------------------
image(x, y, z2, col=colors, breaks=breaks, zlim =zlim, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, 
      xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(0.1, 5.0), xlim=c(0.1, 0.8))
title(ylab=expression(y), line=2.0, cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(xlab=expression(x), line=2.5, cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(main="(b)", adj=0, cex.main=1.5)

#---Subplot 3-------------------------------------------------------------------
image(x, y, z3, col=colors, breaks=breaks, zlim =zlim, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5,
      xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(0.1, 5.0), xlim=c(0.1, 0.8))
title(ylab=expression(y), line=2.0, cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(xlab=expression(x), line=2.5, cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(main="(c)", adj=0, cex.main=1.5)

#---Subplot 4-------------------------------------------------------------------
image(x, y, z4, col=colors, breaks=breaks, zlim=zlim, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, 
      xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(0.1, 5.0), xlim=c(0.1, 0.8))
title(ylab=expression(y), line=2.0, cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(xlab=expression(x), line=2.5, cex.lab=1.5, family='serif')
title(main="(d)", adj=0, cex.main=1.5)

#---Colorbar--------------------------------------------------------------------
imageScale(z=z1, ylim=zlim, zlim=zlim, col=colors, breaks=breaks, axis.pos=2)
text(x=-.875, y=300, labels=expression(g[sc]~(mmol~m^-2~s^-1)), xpd=NA, srt=90,
     cex=1.5, family='serif') 

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: This is useful! But I mentioned that I need only one color bar for all the plots  (see my edited question). How to place color bar (horizontal) (also with horizontal legend) in the middle of the bottom of the plot?

Comment: Perfect! So this is all about setting the layout. This makes sense to me now.